# Keyboard shortcut: shift+tab in chrome does wrong thing

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, web-browsing

I'm a new mac user really (*really*) struggling to learn the mac keyboard shortcuts.  One that is just killing me right now is navigating forms in Chrome.

Say I hit `Tab` to go to the next element in a form.  When i hit `Shift+Tab` to try to return to that element, instead of going back up the form, Chrome navigates to the previous tab.

How do I fix this?  My strong preference is for `Shift-Tab` to simply reverse-navigate the form - that is pretty standard behavior..

Comment: Does Tab forward work correctly? Can you Tab and Shift+Tab in safari, or firefox?

Comment: Yeah, I can tab forward and Shift+Tab backward in firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, or just to check whether the problem is with Google Chrome or something else, install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf).

To configure it to go to the last input, type in <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in *Shortcut Key* and as the *Action*, click Browser Action > Inner Page Action > Focus on the previous input element.

You could also try [Reset Browser Settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en) and then try going back in a form in Incognito Mode - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: Sweet.  Shortcut Manager did the trick nicely. Still seems weird that I needed an extension for that, but so be it. I suspect I'll get more use out of that extension in the future too.

Answer (score -1):

They work for me. Out of curiosity, under the Window menu, what is the keyboard shortcut for "Select Next Tab" and "Select Previous Tab"?

**Edit** (because I'm an idiot and misused SO): If they aren't <kbd>⌥ + ⌘ + →</kbd> and <kbd>⌥ + ⌘ + ←</kbd>, then something's wrong. Check System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and see if they've been redefined there; otherwise, perhaps one of your extensions hijacked <kbd>⇧ + <tab></kbd>?